# Proving a differential equation is a circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

So, I have solved the differential equation, to find the general solution of:

$$\frac{y^2}{2} = 2x - \frac{x^2}{2} + c$$

I am told that is passes through the point $(4,2)$. Using this information, I found $C$ to be $2$. Then I am asked to prove that the equation forms a circle, and find the radius and centre point. So I know to try and get it into the form:

$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

So I can get:

$$\frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2} = 2x + 2$$

Multiply both sides by $2$:

$$y^2 + x^2 = 4x + 4$$

But from here I am not sure how to group the $x$'s to leave only a constant on the RHS. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: you want $(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 4 + 4 = (2\sqrt 2)^2$

Comment: Complete the square in $x^2-4x\cdots$

Comment: What does this have to do with differential equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have,

$$ y^2 +x^2 = 4x+4,$$

what we need to do is group the $x$'s together and complete the square,

$$ y^2 + \left( x^2-4x \right) = 4.$$

So we need to complete the square for the expression $x^2-4x$. The idea is to write this polynomial as a perfect square plus a constant. To do this we first consider the expression $(x+a)^2 = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$. This motivates us to rewrite our polynomial as,

$$ x^2-4x = x^2-2(2)x  = (x-2)^2-2^2 = (x-2)^2-4$$

we can then substitute this back into the original equation to get,

$$ y^2 + \left( x-2\right)^2 = 8.$$

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was after, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint1 :
$$
x^{2}-4x+4+y^{2}=4+4
$$

Hint 2:
$$
x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2
$$

Comment: So are you just adding 4 to both sides? I can get it from this, thank you